# lisp member function on string list

Tags: lisp

I am using LISP and was wondering how I can access a member in a list of strings. I have tried the member function but keep getting NIL.
Thanks

```
(setq phrase-list '( "What color is the sky?"  "It is Blue.")) ;list of strings

(write phrase-list)
(terpri)

(setq x(read-line)) ; I try to input What color is the sky?

(write(member x phrase-list)) ; I keep getting NIL
```

Comment: Why is a question about `lisp` tagged `scheme`?

Comment: Have you verified what string is getting bound to `x`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I should also remove the common-lisp tag as well. I was a little confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the correct test function

```
(member x phrase-list :test #'string=)
```

Alternatively `equal` should work as well.

Some info about Common Lisp [predicates](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node74.html)